# Java Garbage Collector and Field Variables

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I actually have a quick question which I cannot find an answer to.

I am VERY persistant that my Android/Java application eats up the least amount of RAM as possible as it helps the user experience.

With that being said my question is focused on field variables and the garbage collector.

My application will start up and I have a list of set field variables (hardcoded). Now for the sake of readability I have chosen field variables. If I wish to make a quick change I change the value instead of me looking through my code to see when the variable is actually used.

My field variables in this case are only used ONCE, when the application is loaded for the first time.

Does the garbage collector remove this variable or must I set it null manually. I know a simple int value isn't much to cry over, however I am curious as to the garbage collector.

The object which contains the field will always be in use (it will be an Android ViewPagerAdapter in this case).

Comment: There's nothing to collect on a single `int`. An object with an `int` field has a place (4 bytes) for it and there's nothing you could do about it. Leaving it uninitialized is the same as writing there a zero.

Comment: Are they instance or static fields? If they're static, the space taken up is negligible. If they're instance fields, consider making them static.

Comment: Maybe they should be in a .properties file?

Answer (score 2):

Field variables are strong references; as long as that <del>class</del> *object* is around, the field variable must remain accessible. If you're only using them in one method, it'd be (marginally, slightly) more efficient to only keep them in scope for the run of that method.

Comment: As long as that *object* is around.

Comment: Yes, object. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't need explicitly set fields to null, however if you really concern about performance/memory avoid creating fields instead go for local variables i.e. Convert fields to local variable to method if possible and Avoid creating unnecessary fields if they used only once.

Best I would suggest for you is please refer to Android Best practices documentation for app performance improvement

1. http://developer.android.com/training/best-performance.html
2. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html